# How to print from two lists on swift

Tags: arrays, swift, list, random, names

If I have a list of first names, and then a list of second names then how do I print a random selection from 1 of each list

```
let arrayX = ["James", "Andrew", "Sean"]
let arrayY = ["Smith", "Docherty", "Anderson"]
```

So I could have James Smith, or Andrew Anderson?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch String with randomly generated index.

```
let arrayX = ["James", "Andrew", "Sean"]
let arrayY = ["Smith", "Docherty", "Anderson"]

print(arrayX[getRandomIndex(maxRange: arrayX.count)], arrayY[getRandomIndex(maxRange: arrayY.count)])
```

Function to generate random index:

```
func getRandomIndex(maxRange: Int) -> Int{
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxRange)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To select a random item from an array you need to generate a random number within it's index range.

You can do this in Swift using arc4random_uniform:

```
Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayX.count)))
```

Once you know how to do this you can quite easily generate a random name from your arrays:

```
let arrayX = ["James", "Andrew", "Sean"]
let arrayY = ["Smith", "Docherty", "Anderson"]

let randomForenameIdx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayX.count)))
let randomSurnameIdx = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayY.count)))

let randomName = "\(arrayX[randomForenameIdx]) \(arrayY[randomSurnameIdx])"
```

Comment: I have a doubt regarding your this point : **The reason we do - 1 in the index is because the array has a zero-based index. So it starts from 0. if you [1, 2, 3] the indexes are 0, 1, 2.** 

I think it makes the range from 0 to (whaterver range is given) - 1. 

So we don't need to pass arrayX.count - 1 as that will give values 0 and 1 only and never 2.

Comment: the values themselves dont really matter. It can be [4,5,6] the length is 3. so arc4random_uniform(3) will give you values 0, 1, 2, 3 (4 values) so if you dont minus 1 from the count you will get an out of bounds error when the random number is 4 because index 4 doesn't exist

Comment: unless I am mistaken, I will test to confirm

Comment: Yes that's exactly my doubt, I think arc4random_uniform(3) will generate values [0,1,2] 3 values only not 4. Yes please confirm as I am running timer also and its printing [0,1,2] only

Comment: Looks like you are correct, i ran 100k tests and never got the value.. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks for confirming from your side too. :)

Comment: welcome, I had to do this in a web project yesterday and had to do -1. must of been getting confused between the languages random functions

Answer (score 1):

Swift has a very nice way of intertwining arrays using the `zip` function:

```
let firstNames = ["James", "Andrew", "Sean"]
let lastNames = ["Smith", "Docherty", "Anderson"]

let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstNames.count)))
let randomName = Array(zip(firstNames, lastNames))[randomIndex]
print("\(randomName.0) \(randomName.1)")
```

`zip(_:_:)` takes two collections (i. e. arrays) and returns a sequence of tuple pairs, where the elements of each pair are corresponding elements of both collections. The `Array` initialiser converts the result to an Array of tuples.

This solution always matches first and last names, i. e. you either get James Smith, Andrew Doherty, or Sean Anderson. If this is not what you want then you’ll need two random indexes and no `zip` function, as suggested in the other answers.